# removeFromSuperView() and cells = fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm doing a little UITableView with a CustomCell in a XIB.

I want to remove views if a bool says FALSE.

So what I did was a little func :

```
func deleteStackOrNot(valeurPLIST: Bool, stack: UIStackView) {
if valeurPLIST {
    stack.hidden = false

} else {
    stack.removeFromSuperview()
      }
}
```

and then :

```
deleteStackOrNot((corpusArray[indexPath.row]["iconesNPBool"] as! Bool), stack: cell.iconesStackOutlet)
```

It's working great on the first scroll down, on 2 cells. However, when I'm scrolling back to the first cell, I get :

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Pointing on the function call.

I guess I've removed the outlet, like, "for ever", and now xcode doesnt seems to be able to recreate it…

I've also tried with .hidden but I need to remove it, since the constraints stays when the view is hidden.

What do you think ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few alternatives:

1. You could add a UIStackView property to the custom cell class to hold the view while it's not in the hierarchy and add it back
2. You could create an .XIB with just the stack view and construct a new one by loading it.
3. You could recreate the stack view in code if it's nil
4. You could not remove it and just alter the constraints (or its size)

EDIT: To do #1

Add:

```
var hiddenStack: UIStackView?
```

Then, in your func (fill in the right code where the comment is):

```
func deleteStackOrNot(valeurPLIST: Bool, stack: UIStackView) {
   if valeurPLIST {
      // put the hidden stack back in the view here
      // using self.hiddenStack
   } else {
      self.hiddenStack = stack
      stack.removeFromSuperview()
   }
}
```

Comment: I think the fourth option should be just fine, but I've also tried it, however, when I do 

                cell.mapOutlet.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)

Nothing changes…

Comment: That frame might conflict with your constraints. I recommend option #1 as the easiest and most likely to work

Comment: Mmm I'm not sure I understand really what it means, but I'm going to look up on Google, unless someone knows how to make it clear ?

Comment: I had the same issue. Don't really know how right I am, but it works for my needs. The code is simple:

`if let wv = cell.webView {
            if myBool == false {
                wv.removeFromSuperview()
            }
        }`